# How do I render a SVG in Angular as a URL reference rather than using the SVG object itself?

Tags: html, angular, svg, frontend, rendering

I currently have a SVG in a url, that I want to render in Angular via HTML. Because the block I'm trying to render the SVG in is in a for loop, I'm trying to dynamically render the SVG via a URL reference, like below:

Our app has AngularJS AND Angular6, and I was able to render the SVG via url in the AngularJS side using the object tag with ng-attr-data="svgUrl".
I've tried different combinations of img tags and object tags with the newer syntaxes, but am unable to get it to render like in AngularJS.

```
<div class="row checkout-items mb-3" *ngFor="let item of orderSummaryModel.items">
    //For rendering PNG, works fine
    <img *ngIf="!item.color.imageFeatured.includes('mockupSvg')" class="product-image img-fluid" [src]="item.color.imageFeatured" nopin="nopin">      
    //Trying to render SVG here via url 
    <object *ngIf="item.color.imageFeatured.includes('mockupSvg')" [attr.xlink:href]="item.color.imageFeatured" type="image/svg+xml"></object>
</div>
```

The expected result is that the SVG renders, where item.color.imageFeatured is a SVG url. It's currently showing up as blank, with a empty #document, although the SVG url renders fine when opened separately in a browser.

Comment: Does it render if you remove the `*ngIf`?

Comment: @ConnorsFan Nope, no change in the document pretty much

Comment: You can try to use MatIconRegistry from https://material.angular.io/components/icon/api
Or try using this angular package. https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-svg-icon

Comment: What does the value of `item.color.imageFeatured` look like?

Comment: @ConnorsFan "http://mywebsite.com:8080/api/assets/mockupSvg?campaignKey=CM_01&amp;variantKey=keyyy&amp;mockupSize=480

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out guys, turns out that angular has built in XSS defense mechanisms causing the rendering to fail. Fixed by using a sanitizer on the url.

Answer (score 1):

The `<object>` element doesn't have an `xlink:href` attribute.

I think you likely meant:

```
<object *ngIf="item.color.imageFeatured.includes('mockupSvg')"
        [data]="item.color.imageFeatured" type="image/svg+xml"></object>
```